# Radius of convergence of power series (complex)

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

I don't know if my reasoning is right on this exercise:
If the power series $\sum a_n z^n$ has radius of convergence $R$, which is the radius of convergence of the series $\sum a_n^2 z^n$ and $\sum a_n z^{2n}$?

For the first one I am thinking: $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty } \left|\dfrac{a^2_{n+1}}{a^2_n}\right|=\lim_{n \to \infty } \left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|^2$= $R^2$.

And for the second, I believe it must have the same radius $R$, because it has the same coefficients, but we are only taking the pair powers, is this right?

Comment: You need a tool that does not assume every $a_n$ is nonzero. Which ones do you know?

Comment: @Did Isn't it trivial to assume that all $a_n$ are nonzero? If some $a_n$ is zero, it does not contribute to the sum, so you may concatenate the sequence.

Comment: The second series replaces $z$ by $z^2$. Formerly you required $|z|<R$. Now you require $|z^2|<R$, equivalent to $|z|<\sqrt{R}$.

Comment: @alex.jordan The "trivial" argument in your comment is wrong since this "concatenation" changes the power of $z$ corresponding to each nonzero $n$.

Comment: @Did Ah, thanks.

Comment: If $R$ is a radius of convergence of $\sum a_n z^n$ does not mean that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \right|$ exists at all.

Comment: Maybe using the nth rooth? like this? $\frac{1}{\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left| a^2 _n\right|}}$ = $\frac{1}{\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left| a _n\right|^2}}$ and so? this exist because the original radius can be found that way, i believe...

Comment: You *could* use $\limsup$ of the $n$-th root, since that gives an if and only if criterion, though the answer of Did is I think more concrete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The radius of convergence $R$ of the series $\sum\limits_na_nz^n$ is *characterized* by the fact that $|a_n|r^n\to0$ when $r\lt R$ and $|a_n|r^n\not\to0$ when $r\gt R$ (note how one carefully avoids to specify what happens when $r=R$, with reason since several different behaviours are possible).

Thus, $|a_n^2|r^n=(|a_n|(\sqrt{r})^n)^2\to0$ if $\sqrt{r}\lt R$ and $|a_n^2|r^n\not\to0$ if $\sqrt{r}\gt R$. These conditions can be rewritten as $r\lt R^2$ and $r\gt R^2$, respectively, hence the radius of convergence of  $\sum\limits_na_n^2z^n$ is $R^2$.

Surely you can proceed likewise for $\sum\limits_na_nz^{2n}$.